# How do I do a subquery within a SELECT statement in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, postgresql

How do I do a subquery within a SELECT statement in PHP?

For example (I am aware there is a better way to write this query, no need to point it out):

```
SELECT
  product_name
FROM
  (SELECT * FROM product)
```

How would I do this in PHP? I tried the following query, but it did not work:

```
pg_query($conn, 'SELECT product_name FROM SELECT * FROM product')
```

Answer (score 3):

The SQL standard and PostgreSQL require that any subquery in the `FROM` clause has an alias, even if it is not used in the query:

```
SELECT
   product_name
FROM
   (SELECT * FROM product) AS q
```

Comment: Gosh! That worked. Thanks a lot. I couldn't find the answer anywhere on Google.

Comment: Another question, if you don't mind me asking. Are you able to do queries that include WITH clauses in PHP?

Comment: Sure any valid SQL statement is possible.

Answer (score -1):

Depending on the purpose of your task, you could create a `SELECT` subquery, however, I am not sure what your intention is. In your current post, you say is should be

```
SELECT 
    product_name 
FROM 
    SELECT * 
    FROM product
```

When that is run, the `FROM` clause is incorrectly used as the clause could be reduced drastically. If you are trying to just get the product, you could say something like:

```
SELECT 
    product_name 
FROM 
    product
```

If you are trying to get the times the product occurs in your table, if the product is not the Primary Key for instance, you could create a subquery in the SELECT clause like so:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    p.product_name
    (
        SELECT 
            COUNT(*) 
        FROM 
            product prodSub 
        WHERE 
            prodSub.product_name == p.product_name
    ) AS "Occurances"
FROM 
    product p
```

Note that this query should give the idea, and I did not test it out. Please test and verify; If any errors, please post to address.

Comment: Your first statement is illegal SQL. Using a subquery in the `SELECT` list is often a performance killer (at least in PostgreSQL, where you have more efficient join methods than a nested loop), since it can only be processed with a nested loop.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe, my first statement is noting what was asked in the question